# batch reinitialize global variable inside loop and use it outside loop

Tags: variables, batch-file, expansion, delay

firts of all im beginner. i have multiple file in directory which its name contain date, i need to find which file is the latest one(just need the date). this is what i have so far

```
set currentYear=2013
set logDate=0
set tempLogDate=0
set fileName2=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d/b/s "%logDirectory2%"^|findstr /riv "^.*\\[^\\]*%now%[^\\]*$"') do (
set fileName2=%%a
call set fileName2=!fileName2!:!currentYear!=%%
set tempLogDate=%currentYear%!fileName2:~0,4!
if !tempLogDate! GTR %logDate% ( set logDate=%tempLogDate% )
)

echo !logDate!
```

the problem is variable inside loop didnt get change, thanks in advance

*i change some code but still didnt solve... :( what a horrible weeks start

Comment: solved,thanks @peterwright for your pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the valeue of a variable as it is changed within a loop, you need to have `enabledelayedexpansion` invoked (which you have) AND you then need to use !varname! to access the `changing` value; `%varname% accesses the PARSE-TIME value, that is, the inital variable value **BEFORE** the loop was **STARTED**

Comment: thanks for the response, i did play around using your tips,but still the same, i think i need to throughly learn the basic of VARIABLE EXPANSION first before do this, thanks anyway, appreciated it